# images in draggable div get dragged as a group

Tags: jquery, image, move

i know i'm doing something stupid, and would really appreciate some advice.

i've dynamically created div's in a row with four images, and each image must be individually draggable.

the div's i've created look like this:

```
<div id="imageAreaDiv0" class="drag ui-draggable">
    <div id="uconConnectedToUserName02" class="drag ui-draggable">
        <img class="drag ui-draggable" src="UserThumbs_G-L/a/r/harrytushie" alt="harrytushie" title="harrytushie">
    </div>
    <div id="uconConnectedToUserName03" class="drag ui-draggable">
        <img class="drag ui-draggable" src="UserThumbs_G-L/o/e/joeblow" alt="joeblow" title="joeblow">
    </div>
    <div id="uconConnectedToUserName04" class="drag ui-draggable">
        <img class="drag ui-draggable" src="Images/defaultConnectionThumbnail.png" alt="sampleuser000" title="sampleuser000">
    </div>
    <div id="uconConnectedToUserName05" class="drag ui-draggable">
        <img class="drag ui-draggable" src="Images/defaultConnectionThumbnail.png" alt="sampleuser001" title="sampleuser001">
    </div>
</div>
```

the css looks like this:

```
.drag {
margin-right:5px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
cursor: move;
}
```

and the jQuery drag stuff looks like this:

```
    $(".target").css({ opacity:"0.5" });

    $(".drag").draggable({
        zIndex: 3});

    $(".target").droppable({
        cursor: 'move',
        drop:  function(event, ui) {
            var message = event.target.id;
            var connectName = $(ui.draggable).attr('alt');
            if(event.shiftKey) {
                var actionTaken = copyConnection(connectName);
            } else {
                var actionTaken = moveConnection(connectName);
            }
            document.getElementById('errorNotificationArea').innerHTML =
                '<span style="color:red;font-size:12px;"><br>Connection '+connectName+' was '+actionTaken+' to category '+message+'<br><br></span>';
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

but when i drag an image in this row (or any row with more than one image), all of the images in that row move as a block; i.e., they all move at once.

if i turn off dragging on the "wrapper" div (id=imageAreaDiv0), then the images don't drag.

if someone could please tell me what i'm doing wrong, i'd really appreciate it.

thanks!
twistOneUp

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `drag` class from `DIV`s.

Or rewrite your jQuery function to `$('img.drag').draggable()`.

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to be rude...  first time trying to respond to an answer left for me, n00b at stackoverflow and all that...

@ richardneililagan - i tried removing class='drag ui-draggable' from imageAreaDiv0, which left all images in the block not draggable.  the same result occurred when i specified "img.drag" in the jQuery, and the same result occured when i removed the "drag" on the div's that wrap the image.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `draggable()` on all elements with the class of `.drag`. Your container also has the class of `.drag` (as well as your images). So your container is being dragged (with all images inside of it).

Comment: same as first response to richardneililagan, above.  removing class='drag ui-draggable' from the "wrapper" div causes all images contained therein to be not draggable.

i appreciate the advice, tho!  thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle: ( http://jsfiddle.net/swatkins/JJZCm/ ) -- works for me in IE9, FF6, and Chrome 14 -- I removed the `drag` class from the container element (leaving class ui-draggable)

Comment: hi swatkins, i'd like to say Thanks! for the jsfiddle...  yours works fine, i copy your code into my .php script, yours drags, mine - which is generated on the fly, but looks identical - doesn't.  so it's probably something to do with the way it's generated.  aar, thanks again very much!